# Registering New Custom Culture on Windows for .Net Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, culture

So recently I have needed to have my web application available to users in Saudi Arabia. We got them set up in ar-SA but that presented some problems as the base calendar and symbols weren't what we wanted. So we decided to try and create a new culture, but when I try to register a culture with code ar-SAR or ar-ZZ (Just trying anything here), the same code succeeds registering it on 1 server (windows server 2019) but fails on another server (windows server 2012R2)

Why is it failing?

Here is the script to register the new culture:
(We compile the script using "csc /r:sysglobl.dll culture.cs" in the command line, and then executing the .exe created)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace CultureRegistration
    {
        class CultureLdml
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder carib = CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml("ar-ZZ.ldml");
                carib.Register();
            }
        }
    }
```

Which is failing with error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: Culture is
not supported.
Parameter name: name
ar-ZZ is an invalid culture identifier. ---> System.Globalization.CultureNotFoun
dException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
ar-ZZ is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(String name)
   at System.Globalization.CultureXmlReader.ReadIdentityElement()
   at System.Globalization.CultureXmlReader.Parse()
   at System.Globalization.CultureXmlReader..ctor(String fileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Globalization.CultureXmlReader..ctor(String fileName)
   at System.Globalization.CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CreateFromLdml(String xmlFileName)
   at CultureRegistration.CultureLdml.Main(String[] args)
```

Thank you

Comment: What is your target version of Net/Core?  How did you install the code on the IIS?  Did you publish the code?  A c# application with Net will not run on a deployed machine unless the server version of Net is installed on build and deploy machine; or you publish the code and run setup.exe on remote machine.  Core uses a Run Time library which must be installed which should handle differences in build and deployed machines.

Comment: We are using 4.0.30319
I didn't install any code on IIS for this, its not needed.
We just compile the script above into an exe to add the culture, but it's failing with the error message above. The code is running but its failing

Comment: You are using Net 4.0 which is over 10 years old.  Not sure if this is a bug that has been fixed or a coding issue.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why this has worked for other cultures, but not this new one, and why I am getting that error. You think its simply because of the .NET version?